# Using class methods from libraries in a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I am just trying to create a simple cookbook in chef. I am using libraries as a learning process.

```rb
module ABC
  class YumD
    def self.pack (*count)
      for i in 0...count.length
        yum_packag "#{count[i]}" do
          action :nothing
        end.run_action :install
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I call this in the recipe I get a compile error which says

```
undefined method `yum_package' for ABC::YumD:Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have access to the Chef Recipe DSL inside libraries. The DSL methods are actually just shortcuts to full-blown Ruby classes. For example:

```rb
template '/etc/foo.txt' do
  source 'foo.erb'
end
```

Actually "compiles" (read: "is interpreted") to:

```rb
template = Chef::Resource::Template.new('/etc/foo.txt')
template.source('foo.erb')
template.run_action(:create)
```

So, in your case, you want to use `YumPackage`:

```rb
module ABC
  class YumD
    def self.pack(*count)
      for i in 0...count.length
        package = Chef::Resource::YumPackage.new("#{count[i]}")
        package.run_action(:install)
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks got it.  However I get error for `package.run_action(:install). The error that I get is 'undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass' .. package.action just works fine. But I need to install the packages at compile time cos I download a gem using chef_gem which depends on the package.

Comment: Way late to the party, but I think the reason this doesn't work is that the constructor is missing `run_context`. But that doesn't seem to be available from the library.

Comment: The answer I was looking for was how to use a class method in my recipe and the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835697/how-to-require-my-library-in-chef-ruby-block helped me.

You have to define the method with `def self.<<method_name>>` and then you can reference it in your recipe with `AppHelper.<<method_name>>

Answer (score 2):

To improve on sethvargo's answer, which should avoid the `undefined method events for nil:NilClass` error: try adding `run_context` to the constructor call:

```rb
module ABC
  class YumD
    def self.pack(*count)
      for i in 0...count.length
        package = Chef::Resource::YumPackage.new("#{count[i]}", run_context)
        package.run_action(:install)
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: SO would not let me comment on the original post by Sbal. Blame them, not me. And if I'm not answering the question, neither is sethvargo, yet I don't see you complain about his post.

Comment: I think you're on to something but when I try it, `run_context` is undefined.

Comment: Easy fix: create a new run_context, like this: `run_context = Chef::RunContext.new(Chef::Node.new, {}, Chef::EventDispatch::Dispatcher.new)`

Comment: @JosBackus tried that. Fails with `ArgumentError: Cannot find a platform for node[]`. Any idea about how to pass the platform information to the Chef::Node object?

Comment: @JosBackus to answer my own question:

`#!/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby

require 'chef'
require 'ohai'

node = Chef::Node.new
node.automatic = Ohai::System.new.all_plugins[0].data

run_context = Chef::RunContext.new(node, {}, Chef::EventDispatch::Dispatcher.new)
package = Chef::Resource::Package.new 'git', run_context
package.run_action :install`

LE: Please ignore the useless formatting for code in comments.

Comment: @SaltwaterC the Ohai call sets up the platform, which is why it now works and not before. Glad you got it to work.