# How to use a chef helper library from another chef cookbook in a ruby_block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

AWS Opsworks: Chef version 11.10, Berkshelf version 3.2.0.

**I can't figure out how to use a helper library from cookbook A in a `ruby_block` in cookbook B.**

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835697/how-to-require-my-library-in-chef-ruby-block) discussing how to include a method in a ruby_block and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333486/how-do-i-share-code-across-chef-cookbooks-in-a-chef-repo) discussing how to share libraries across cookbooks but I can't get both working at the same time.

cookbookA/libraries/helpers.rb

```ruby
module libraryA
    module Helpers
        def log(output)
            Chef::Log.info("#{cookbook_name}:#{recipe_name}: #output}")
        end
    end
end
```

cookbookB/metadata.rb

```ruby
depends 'cookbookA'
```

The following setup.rb works.

cookbookB/recipes/setup.rb

```ruby
 ::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, libraryA::Helpers)
 log("this is a log")
```

However, when I use the log function in a ruby block, it fails. **The following setup.rb does not work:**

cookbookB/recipes/setup.rb

```ruby
 ::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, libraryA::Helpers)
 ruby_block "logging-function" do
      block do
           log("this is a log")
      end
 end
```

P.S.: I have also tried using `::Chef::Resource.send(:include, 
libraryA::Helpers)`

Updated code block:

```ruby
::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, libraryA::Helpers) 
ruby_block "logging-test" do 
    block do 
        ::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, libraryA::Helpers)    
        ::libraryA::Helpers.ttlog("message") 
    end 
end
```

Received error: NoMethodError - undefined method ttlog for libraryA::Helpers:Module

Updated helpers

cookbookA/libraries/helpers.rb

```ruby
def log(output)
    Chef::Log.info("#{cookbook_name}:#{recipe_name}: #output}")
end
```

P.S: Removed the modules structure

Comment: According to Sethvargo's answer on the first link you provided library's are loaded in the global namespace so you can use a fully qualified access to your method: `block { libraryA::Helpers.log("message") }` should do. (Side note: I did use brackets instead of do end as I wrote it as a one liner, but that does not change the behavior)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I have tried using the fully qualified access. But I am receiving an error "undefined method `log' ".

Comment: May you update the question with the full error output ? (does it show fully qualified method or not ?) I would also recommend using another name to avoid conflict with chef `log` resource

Comment: @Tensibai Hi. Sorry for the delayed response. The error does not show fully qualified method. It shows (ttlog is method name - changed it from log)                                                                                  `NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method ttlog for Chef::Resource::RubyBlock`

Comment: Are youvusing a full method inside the ruby block ? An update of the question could be great to see where the error comes from

Comment: This is how I am using it (included the helpers inside and out of the block just to be sure. Also the error is NoMethodError-------------
undefined method ttlog for libraryA::Helpers:Module):                                                            `::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, libraryA::Helpers)                          ruby_block "logging-test" do
    block do
        ::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, libraryA::Helpers)
        ::libraryA::Helpers.ttlog("hey there")
    end
end`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. I have been able to resolve the issue. I have changed the format of the helpers.rb to be pure definitions without wrapping them into modules. This way, I can access the functions both inside and outside of a resource. The new code looks as follows:   
       * def ttlog(output)
            Chef::Log.info("#{cookbook_name}:#{recipe_name}: #output}")
        end *

Comment: **def ttlog(output)                                                                          Chef::Log.info("#{cookbook_name}:#{recipe_name}: #output}")            end**

Comment: You should add this as an answer and mark it as accepted answer after 1 or 2 days

Comment: Ho. And please [edit] the question to show last step before resolution so it can help others later ;)

Comment: @Tesibai Done !!!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think ruby_block runs in other context, under other object.
You can try to include that library into provider, but I can't guarantee it would work.

`::Chef::Provider::RubyBlock.send(:include, libraryA::Helpers)`

ps. Resource does have definition and list of parameters, but code is executed from Provider.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I do remember reading about providers. However, currently our code is not provider based. We are however planning to move to provider soon. I will definitely try this when we do.